# convert java.util.Date directly into desired format?

Tags: java

How to convert java.util.Date directly into desired Date format ?
I have tried to convert the date into string first and then again into date but it still takes date format as Mar 10,2011, i want this format as 10-03-2011

Comment: The usual answer for you: `java.util.Date` is merely a representation of a millisecond in time since January 1st 1970 GMT. `Date` objects have **NO** information of format. If you want to print out dates use `SimpleDateFormat` and not the `toString()` method of `Date`. Latter is rather confusing to most programmers

Comment: please take a look at this before asking questions related to date formats http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: you say you need the Date object for sorting purposes? How are you visually displaying the string object? Is it in a Swing application.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple :) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can help you out.

But if you have datestring then yes you need to parse the *datestring* to date and re-format it again to desired format(`dd-MM-yyyy`).

Comment: yes i have tried it but SimpleDateFormat converts the date into string but i need the Date datatype as it is instead of string for sorting purpose,will you please put your idea with code ?

Comment: if your input is string then parse it using `SimpleDateFOrmat#parse` which convert string to date and you can re convert it again

Comment: My code is like this: java.util.Date date = <Object>.getDate; then i did this new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date); for getting desired format but while displaying it in jtable i need the date as Date and not as String

Comment: because while sorting date in ascending or descending order it must be treated as Date instead of String

Comment: What I can get for you [Date in a JTable and a JTextField in "DD/MM/YYYY" format](http://www.coderanch.com/t/334651/GUI/java/Date-JTable-JTextField-DD-MM)

Answer (score 1):

OP failed to mention that he is displaying these in a **JTable**. You need these things for your date column in your JTable.

- A **CellRenderer** : This will display the date in its string format (Use Simpledateformat)
- A **TableModel** : This holds the internal representation

Now when you sort the JTable, the column will sort on the internal data representation.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, new Locale("en_US"));
String tDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(tDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in your date object directy to this method and you'll get the date in desired string format

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String date = format.format(Date.parse(objectDate.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SimpleDateFormat` with the date format dd-MM-yyyy:

```
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String date = dateFormat.format(today);
System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : " + date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

for 10-03-2011 your format should be "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: I have tried variations like this :                      SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  String stringDate = sf.format(date);
         Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(stringDate);

Comment: but still it is displaying date in JTable as Mar 10,2011 but i need date to be displayed in jTable as 10-03-2011